# Enormous JMeter Results file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm running a very simple JMeter test (screenshot attached) that hits 2 web pages.  It's set to run for 6 hours but for some reason, the report is enormous.  The last run came out at 41GB and as a result, I cannot generate the HTML report.

Any ideas as to why it's so big and what I can do about it? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're running a test with 100 users for 6 hours and each user creates a separate line for each page in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) like this:

```
1657532286921,298,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,1591,116,1,1,http://example.com/,295,0,163
```

so it's roughly 100 bytes per user per page

One iteration (100 users hitting 2 pages) would be 19 kilobytes

If response time of each page is 1 second each user will be able to execute 1800 requests per hour and 10800 requests per 6 hours. 100 users will execute 1080000 requests resulting in 108 gigabytes of results file.

There is nothing you can do about the results file size, you could increase JMeter's heap space so the file would fit into memory (if you don't have enough RAM you can use [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging) for this)

Alternative option is using [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) to send the results to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/), in this case JMeter will send only aggregate data and the size will be lower, the results can be visualized in Grafana. More information: [JMeter + Grafana: How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana)